# How to get cursor positions on click and drag event in python?

Tags: python, tkinter, mouseevent, drag, cursor-position

I want to get all the **cursor positions till i left click and drag** the mouse on the tkinter widget screen in python.

The below code just provides the left click position and not the positions on dragging the mouse after left click event.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

def leftClick(event):
    x, y = event.x, event.y
    print('({}, {}) -> LEFT'.format(x,y))

root.bind('<Button-1>',leftClick)

root.mainloop()
```

Is there any way to get positions of **drag** event

Comment: Read up on [Events and Bindings](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm) and

Answer (score 1):

I built a screen snipping program and here is one of the methods from it.

```
  def on_move_press(self, event):
        self.curX, self.curY = (event.x, event.y)
        # expand rectangle as you drag the mouse
        print(self.curX)
        print(self.curY)
        self.screenCanvas.coords(self.rect, self.start_x, self.start_y, self.curX, self.curY)
```

This will dynamically update when the user drags the snipping rectangle and print the values of the Current X and Current Y position (until the user releases).

This is activated by using the B1-Motion arguement as seen below.

```
self.screenCanvas.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.on_move_press)
```

Hopefully this helps!